# Remove ASUS ROG UEFI boot branding from laptop

Tags: windows-10, uefi, bootloader, secure-boot

I was asked to purchase a laptop with a 17" screen for a customer who owns a restaurant, so I bought an ASUS ROG G750JM.  It's a very capable laptop and has nice features and build quality.

However, when it boots up there's a less-than-professional looking "Republic of Gamers" screen that displays while Windows 10 is being loaded.

I thought this branding was in the EFI partition, so I actually nuked the partition and re-built it using a stock Windows 10 Enterprise install USB.  But the branding is still there!

Where is this branding stored, and how can I get rid of it?  Is it tied to a secureboot key or some thing else stored in the BIOS?

Comment: try this tool to change the logo: https://github.com/Metabolix/HackBGRT

Comment: does the tool work for you?

Comment: Hackzbgrt is just that - a hack. Use the ASUS ROG MyLogo utility to permanently change the logo.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to add an answer. You can always add an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2):

This is called the "splash screen" and is typically stored in the boot settings of your BIOS. Nearly every mobo company has this, but ROG boards are the top end of the Asus line and they are targeted at gamers, who use computers more completely than most anyone else does.

To disable it, go into the BIOS settings (<kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>, usually) and navigate to the boot menu. You should see an option for disabling the splash screen and showing the POST details there.   Enabling "Fast Boot" also tends to hide the BIOS splash screen.

---

**UPDATE**: This is Asus Specific. Asus has their own utility to manually change the motherboard splash screen to anything you want. It's called [MyLogo.](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1012430/) It's a free utility on the motherboard DVD. Don't have the DVD? [The disc download for this model is here, and what you need is in Drivers and Tools.](https://www.asus.com/supportonly/G750JM/HelpDesk_Download/)

If the download doesn't contain the utility because it's a laptop, I'm sure someone at Asus support can get you the file you need. I strongly doubt you're the first ROG customer who didn't want a serious client that still thinks video games are for children to see ”Republic of Gamers” across the boot screen.

Comment: I thought enabling fast boot typically skips the POST details and goes straight to the splash screen (?) - oh well, I haven't tried it yet - it's worth a shot.

Comment: Normally, splash hides a lot of post details.  If there's enough additional hardware that is checked on boot, fast boot may not hide the logo, but in simple machines it usually just boots fast enough the logo never gets loaded.

Comment: Ahh.  Yes, that is probably more true of NVMe computers, but this one is a few years old so it's relegated to SATA3.  The 860 EVO saturates the bus, but it's no NVMe.

Comment: I dunno, my  Sata II Intel 128GB SSD is in a SataIII port and fastboot skips it for me, but the motherboard is probably much newer.  Lemme think on this one, I might be able to come up with a solution...

Comment: Found one.   Let us know if it works!

Answer (score 1):

If your ASUS motherboard has "[Asus AI Suite 3](https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1012152/)" listed in the 
[Driver & Utility]-->[OS]-->[Utilities] 
section of the ASUS website, you can use the EZ UPDATE feature to change your boot logo.

It wasn't clear to me that first you need to select the BIOS update file, then you get a 'My Logo' choice that lets you specify your logo image.